# sed - remove a block of lines of shortest size between two strings

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a specific issue, I would like to remove a block of lines between 2 strings but these strings appear also in other parts of the file to process.

For example, I have the following file :

```
<table><tr><td>
<a name="tex2html559" href="node4.html">
<img width="37" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="next" src="next.gif"></a> 

 </td>
<td>
<a name="tex2html555" href="node2.html">
<img width="26" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="up" src="up.gif"></a> 

</td>
<td>
<a name="tex2html549" href="node2.html">
<img width="63" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="previous" src="prev.gif"></a> 
</td>
<td>
<a name="tex2html557" href="node1.html">
<img width="65" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="contents" src="contents.gif"></a> 
</td>
</tr></table>
<br>
<table><tr><td><b> suivant:</b> <a name="tex2html560" href="node4.html">G&#233;n&#233;ralisation de la notion</a></td><td>

<b> monter:</b> <a name="tex2html556" href="node2.html">Les vecteurs</a>
</td><td>
<b> pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent:</b> <a name="tex2html550" href="node2.html">Les vecteurs</a>
 &nbsp; <b>  <a name="tex2html558" href="node1.html">Table des mati&#232;res</a></b>  </td>
</tr>
</table> 

<img width="629" height="54" border="0" src="img34.gif" alt="\begin{displaymath}\begin{array}[b]{lclr}
{A^{i}_{}}_{j}\,x^{i}\,y^{j}
&amp;=&amp;{A^{1}...
...}_{2}\,x^{2}\,y^{2}
&amp;(\text{sommation sur $j$}) \\
\end{array}\end{displaymath}">
</div><p></p>

<table><tr><td>
<a name="tex2html559" href="node4.html">
<img width="37" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="next" src="next.gif"></a>

 </td>
<td>
<a name="tex2html555" href="node2.html">
<img width="26" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="up" src="up.gif"></a>

</td>
<td>
<a name="tex2html549" href="node2.html">
<img width="63" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="previous" src="prev.gif"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a name="tex2html557" href="node1.html">
<img width="65" height="24" align="BOTTOM" border="0" alt="contents" src="contents.gif"></a>
</td>
</tr></table>
<br>
<table><tr><td><b> suivant:</b> <a name="tex2html560" href="node4.html">G&#233;n&#233;ralisation de la notion</a></td><td>
<b> monter:</b> <a name="tex2html556" href="node2.html">Les vecteurs</a>
</td><td>
<b> pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent:</b> <a name="tex2html550" href="node2.html">Les vecteurs</a>
 &nbsp; <b>  <a name="tex2html558" href="node1.html">Table des mati&#232;res</a></b>  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like to remove only the block :

```
<img width="629" height="54" border="0" src="img34.gif" alt="\begin{displaymath}\begin{array}[b]{lclr}
{A^{i}_{}}_{j}\,x^{i}\,y^{j}
&amp;=&amp;{A^{1}...
...}_{2}\,x^{2}\,y^{2}
&amp;(\text{sommation sur $j$}) \\
\end{array}\end{displaymath}">
</div><p></p>
```

I tried to do :

```
sed '/<img.*/, /<\/div><p><\/p>/d'
```

and I get the output :

```
<table><tr><td>
<a name="tex2html559" href="node4.html">

<table><tr><td>
<a name="tex2html559" href="node4.html">
```

It seems that `sed` takes account of the other `<img` tags and remove all from these tags.

How to indicate the shortest block above to be removed ?

ps: I have multiple HTML files like this (where this block has different sizes), so I would like an automatic processing like with `sed` or `awk`.

Thanks

Comment: You are also removing the closing `</div>` tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
sed -n -e '/^$/b a' -e 'H;$ b a' -e 'b' -e :a -e 'x;/<\/div><p><\/p>/!p'
```

**EDIT:**

This part:

```
-e '/^$/b a'
```

means "if the line is empty, jump to **a**".

This:

```
-e 'H;$ b a'
```

means "add the line to the hold space, and then if this is the last line, jump to **a**".

This:

```
-e 'b'
```

means "jump to the end of the script (i.e. conclude, do no more work on this line, start anew on the next line)".

This:

```
-e :a -e 'x;/<\/div><p><\/p>/!p'
```

means "here is **a**. Swap the contents of the pattern space and the hold space (i.e. retrieve all we have collected), and if it does not contain `<div><p></p>` then print it (otherwise -- if it *does* contain `<div><p></p>`, do not print it)".

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain briefly how do you proceeed ? '/^$/b a means you branch to label a ? H is for hold space ?

Answer (score 0):

From your sed command, Why you can't mention the width size.

```
sed '/<img width="629"/, /<\/div><p><\/p>/d'
```

Comment: because I have multiple files and the parameter "width" has not the same value for each one

Comment: @user1773603 The code is worked or not? If the width is not same then you can use that!

Comment: your command line works (for this specific file) but I have a lot of files to process and the value of the width of this <img tag changes, I don't want to have to manually specify the value of this width